# Get Instance should return object of type implementor class or of type interface

Tags: java, interface

I have the following class:

```
public class NinjaImpl implements Ninja{
   private NinjaImple () {}
   public static Ninja getInstance() {return Singleton.instance;}
   private static class Singleton
   {
        private static final Ninja instance = new NinjaImpl();
   }

   // Implementation
}
```

I have a design discussion with a colleague. Should the inner class hold a variable of type NinjaImpl or of type ninja. In the same way should `getInstance()` return Ninja or NinjaImpl?

Answer (score 2):

Normally `getInstance()` should return the interface, as it allows you to change the implementing class without affecting the users of the interface.

However, since in your case `getInstance()` is a method of the implementing class, the users of `getInstance()` already have a dependency on the implementing class regardless of the type it returns, so it doesn't really matter, and I'm not sure it is even useful to define the `Ninja` interface at all in this case.

It would make more sense to return the interface if `getInstance()` would be a method of some factory class (lets call it `NinjaFactory`), which may return any implementation of the `Ninja` interface it chooses to return.

Comment: So getInstance() is part of the interface? If it is then only factory classes should create ninjas.

Comment: @qballer No, getInstance() is a static method. It should be part of the NinjaFactory class (Unless you don't have a Ninja interface at all, in which case it can remain a static method of the NinjaImpl class).

Comment: Or in Java 8 `getInstance` can be defined in `Ninja`.

Comment: If you will notice the inner static class and the static method is a way to implement singleton which is why I feel this area isn't good. Off course factory class can provide singleton properties.